# Finding closed form transition probabilities of Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Suppose we have two boxes and $2N$ cards, of which $N$ are blue and $N$ are
> red. Initially, $N$ of the cards are placed in box 1, and the remainder
> of the cards are placed in box
> 2. At each trial a card is chosen at random from each of the boxes, and the two cards are put back in the opposite boxes. Let $X_0$ denote
> the number of blue cards initially in box 1 and, let $X_n$ for $n \ge 1$, be
> the number of blue cards in box 1 after the $n$th trial. Find the closed
> form transition probabilities of the Markov chain $X_n, n \ge 0$.

Attempt:
Using $i =$ number of blue balls in box 1 at the beginning of each trial and $j=$ number of blue ball in box 1 at end of each trial. I think there are three cases:

1. Draw red card from box 1 and blue card from box 2, then swap. Since drawing from each of the two boxes are independent, the probability of this case would be $\frac{(N-i)i}{N^2}$
2. Draw blue card from box 1 and red from box 2, then swap. Similarly, this would be $\frac{(N-1)(i)}{N^2}$
3. Draw same coloured cards from box 1 and box 2, then swap. This would be $2\frac{i^2}{N^2}$

Is this all the cases, and their corresponding probabilities? I feel like something is off...

And I'm also not sure how to write the closed form transition probabilities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be the state which denotes that $i$ blue balls are in box 1. That is, $N-i$ blue balls in box 2. 
Total number of states is $N+1: \hspace{1em}$ $Y_0, Y_1, \ldots, Y_N$.

Then, the outgoing transitions from $Y_i$ are only to $Y_{i-1}$, $Y_{i+1}$ and $Y_i$ itself. 
Transition $Y_i \to Y_{i-1}$ : Blue ball is chosen from box 1 and red from box 2. There are $i$ blue balls in box 1, and $i$ red balls in box 2. Thus, P($Y_i \to Y_{i-1}) = (i/N)^2 $

Transition $Y_i \to Y_{i+1}$ : Red ball is chosen from box 1 and blue from box 2. There are $N-i$ blue balls in box 1, and $N-i$ red balls in box 2. Thus, P($Y_i \to Y_{i+1}) = ((N-i)/N)^2 $

Also, $P(Y_i \to Y_{i}) = 1-(i/N)^2-((N-i)/N)^2  = 2(i(N-i)/N^2) $